# AutoCompleteBox in Wp8

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile

I am using autocomplete box in Wp8 but i want to show to different things in textbox of autocomplete box but it is taking only one value , I want to show both First Name and Last name , but it is taking only firstname as selected Iten

Comment: Improve the question & put some code of your's...

Comment: I think your question might be if you type lastname also total name must be displayed ,if so this will be helpfull place parameter  FilterMode="Contains"

Comment: Tell us what you have done?

Comment: No see there is only One item template ok , But what about the textbox of autocomplete . In that textbox i want both last and first name , But it is coming ,only first name